# Output HTML collections as a list JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, innerhtml, htmlcollection

I'm Trying to turn HTML element contents into a list using JavaScript. I'm using this code but it's only returning the last option - "option 6" - instead of each option line by line.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing please?

```js
  var getOptions = document.getElementsByClassName("aofi");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < getOptions.length; i++) {

  document.getElementById("NewOutput").innerHTML = "<li>" + getOptions[i].innerHTML + "</li>";
}
```

```html
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 4</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 5</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 6</h2>
</div>

<div id="NewOutput"></div>
```

Comment: because you keep replacing the innerHTML, not concatenating to it. Each iteration in the loop you are setting the innerHTML with that one value. So when the loop is done, you get the last one since nothing overwritten it.

Comment: On each iteration you are replacing the content. And take care you are inserting a list of <li> elements without <ul> wrapper here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("NewOutput").innerHTML` is a property of your element. If you assign a value to this property, the old value will be overwritten.

You should use

```
document.getElementById("NewOutput").innerHTML += "<li>" + 
//---------------------------------------------^
  getOptions[i].innerHTML + "</li>";
}
```

Thus you will add to the `innerHTML` rather than overwrite it

P.S. `a += b` is a shortcut for `a = a + b`

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the innerHTML each time. Once you hit the last one it is just going to replace the innerHTML with the value of the last elem.

Update your code to use:

```
document.getElementById("NewOutput").innerHTML +=
```

The += being the important bit as it says to add to what already exists.

```js
  var getOptions = document.getElementsByClassName("aofi");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < getOptions.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("NewOutput").innerHTML += "<li>" + getOptions[i].innerHTML + "</li>";
}
```

```html
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 4</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 5</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 6</h2>
</div>

<div id="NewOutput"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will meet your criteria:

```js
const h2s = document.querySelectorAll("h2"),
      output = document.querySelector("#NewOutput")

h2s.forEach(h2 => output.innerHTML += `<li>${h2.innerText}</li>`)
```

```html
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 4</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 5</h2>
</div>
<div class="allOptions">
  <h2 class="aofi">option 6</h2>
</div>

<div id="NewOutput"></div>
```

Comment: That's not what the OP ask for.

Comment: @Alexis thanks mate, just edited, should probably have double checked the OPs request ahah